# Why Can't Phaser Load a Sprite when it's in another function?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hello community of Stack Overflow,

I'm getting started with using both JavaScript and the Phaser framework. I'm playing around with creating sprites right now, and the code from where I'm creating the sprite from is in a separate function from the "create"/creator function. This is my sprite code:

```
player1 = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'Billy')

player1.setBounce(0.2);
player1.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
```

So far, when I put the code to create the sprite in my "create" funtion, it loads in fine without issues. However, once I put it into a separate function (which I will refer to as `player1Create`) and call it from the create function, it ceases to work, and gives me the following error message:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at player1Create (playerRules.js?autoVer=%270.00002%27:2:24)
```

I tried to include the function into the scene property in the config object, but this doesn't change the result or error log. I also added "return player1" to the function and assigned the variable of the same name in the creator function to equal `player1Create`, but again, doesn't change anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (sorry if my question sounds a little noobish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well depending on your phaser game *"structure"*, it could a few different things, but I assume your `config` looks something like this:

```
let config = {
    ...
    scene: { create},
};
```

If so, the problem is, that your new function `player1Create` doesn't get added automatically to the *"Phaser-Object"*, so the easy solution would be to pass the current `this` from the `create` function to the `player1Create`.

something like this:

```
 function create(){
     ...
     player1Create(this);
 }

 function player1Create(scene) {  
     ...
     // see here "scene" was used to create the sprite
     player1 = scene.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'Billy')
     ...
 }
```

now the code should work, but now in your `player1Create` function you will have to use the parameter `scene` instead of `this`.

**Alternate Version:**

If you want to use `this` inside your function, with having to pass the this keyword / object, there are several other options the might look a bit weird (here the two most common):

1. use the `call` function and pass the current `this` object ([checkout the documentation for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call))

   player1Create.call(this);
2. use the `bind` function, to bind the `this` to the function ([checkout the documentation for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind))

   player1Create.bind(this)();

> **btw.:** If you would have share some more code, it would be easier to help. For future question, Check out this [article on how the create good questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), this might help.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help! If I can ask a follow-up question: What defines the "this" variable/value?

Comment: Well the `this` is abit hart to explain, but i will try ([here is a link to a documentation for detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). Basically it has to do with "object oriented programming". In Js if you create an Object you can add "functions" and "variable" to them, and when you want to access those functions/variables you need to use `this`. It sets more or less a "scope".  And internally phaser creates an "object" and adds the `create` function to it.

Comment: But you could create your own "object" like in [this example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src\scenes\scene%20from%20es6%20class.js). Phaser has many ways to do things. ;-) For more information on javascript object/classes [checkout this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), I hope this helps.